# Android - Error inflecting class fragment

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, android-fragments

I have two fragments and one main activity having navigation drawer. In the navigation drawer I have two menu items i.e. Home and Places. I have created xml fragments for both menu items.

**fragment_home.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:padding="0dp"
tools:context="com.gaurav.googlemap.HomeMap" >

<fragment
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
</fragment>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**fragment_places.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Places"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**Java Code**

```
package com.beproject.ourway;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;


public class MainHome extends FragmentActivity{
    private String[] mNavigationDrawerItemTitles;
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ListView mDrawerList;
    Fragment fragment = null;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_home);

    // Initialization

    mNavigationDrawerItemTitles= getResources().getStringArray(R.array.navigation_drawer_items_array);
    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);


    // Defining drawer items
    ObjectDrawerItem[] drawerItem = new ObjectDrawerItem[2];

    drawerItem[0] = new ObjectDrawerItem(R.drawable.ic_launcher, "Home");
    drawerItem[1] = new ObjectDrawerItem(R.drawable.ic_launcher, "Places");


    DrawerItemCustomAdapter adapter = 
            new DrawerItemCustomAdapter(this, R.layout.home_drawer_item, drawerItem);

    mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);

    mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());

    // selectItem(0);
}

public class DrawerItemClickListener implements ListView.OnItemClickListener {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        selectItem(position);
    }

}

void selectItem(int position) {



    switch (position) {
    case 0:
        fragment = new HomeFragment();
        break;
    case 1:
        fragment = new PlacesFragment();
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }

    if (fragment != null) {

        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).commit();

        mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
        mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
        getActionBar().setTitle(mNavigationDrawerItemTitles[position]);

    } else {
        Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
    }
}

public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

    public HomeFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

        return rootView;
    }

}

public class PlacesFragment extends Fragment {

    public PlacesFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_places, container, false);

        return rootView;
    }

}
}
```

**Problem**

When I run the project, I click on Home menu then it shows me home fragment with map in well manner. After that I click on Places then it shows me fragment of places fine. 
But when I again click on Home then my application is getting crashed with following exception

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.gaurav.googlemap/com.gaurav.googlemap.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class fragment
```

Is there any correction in java file to open fragments appropriately?
Thanks

**LogCat**

```
02-16 16:50:58.324: V/Provider/Setting(25249): from settings cache , name = sound_effects_enabled value = 0
02-16 16:50:58.358: D/AndroidRuntime(25249): Shutting down VM
02-16 16:50:58.359: W/dalvikvm(25249): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4188b908)
02-16 16:50:58.388: E/AndroidRuntime(25249): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-16 16:50:58.388: E/AndroidRuntime(25249): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class fragment
02-16 16:50:58.388: E/AndroidRuntime(25249):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
02-16 16:50:58.388: E/AndroidRuntime(25249):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
02-16 16:50:58.388: E/AndroidRuntime(25249):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
```

Comment: Please post your full LogCat

Comment: I think its because you are using support.v4.app.FragmentActivity with android.app.Fragment, you should be using support.v4.app.Fragment

Comment: where to change in my code? @SboneloMbhamali

Comment: @93gaurav93: extend `SupportMapFragment` in `HomeFragment` instead of `Fragment`

Comment: delete this line: import android.app.Fragment; and replace it with import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;

Comment: This also didn't work :(

Comment: error is in   class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"

Answer (score 0):

When we go through fragment life-cycle it seems like when fragment is again calling from onDestroyView() , unbale to call onCreateView(). So my suggestion is that saveInstance of fragment by method

> addToBackStack()

or use

> SetRetainState(true)

Comment: where to and how to put this method in my code? I don't know about this

Comment: I have modified my code but this is not working... :(

Answer (score 0):

Check your mainfaist file if you have all permissions needed for implementing `googleMap`,  look [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start).
If all the permissions are fine, try changing your code like below :

Because you are using `SupportMapFragment` and your variable `Fragment` in `selectItem` method somtimes contains the `HomeFragment` class (in which is the map), you should import this :

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
```

and this line :

```
 FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
```

you should change to :

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
```

and import this :

```
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
```

beacuse of the same reason i have mentioned above.

Hope this will help you.